# asp.net webforms dynamic routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I have a table in sql server with pages and each page created has a slug.  What I've been doing is foreach page in the table get the slug and do this:

```
 routes.MapPageRoute(page.Slug, page.Slug, "~/page.aspx?id=" + page.Id, true, new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary { { "id", page.Id } });
```

so far this works perfectly.  My issue is that this runs on global.asax file on application start so if I create a new page that mapping doesn't work unless i restart the website in iis.  I was reading this post by [haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/17/editable-routes.aspx/) but haven't been able to get it to work yet and not sure if this would solve it, cause in theory when creating a page it should refresh automatically all routing..any ideas?

So when using RouteMagic I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at this line:

```
RouteTable.Routes.RegisterRoutes("~/Config/Routes.cs");
```

Comment: What's the specific issue? Are you attaching the `ConfigFileChangeNotifier` delegate?

Comment: @beautifulcoder how do i attach it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing dynamic compilation. Check in the sample code where it dynamically compiles the code

```
var assembly = BuildManager.GetCompiledAssembly("~/Config/Routes.cs");
var registrar = assembly.CreateInstance("Routes") as IRouteRegistrar;
```

Also, make sure `Route.cs` is set to Content so it doesn't statically compile.

Comment: those 2 lines are the ones that i don't know where to add them.  is it whenever i need to recreate the routes?

Comment: Did you go through the sample code? It should tell you there

Comment: that's the thing i tried to download the sample code and it's no longer available: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/17/editable-routes.aspx/