# How to Recompile Global.asax file programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, global-asax

I am custom CMS where i add dynamic routes from database sample code is below

```
 foreach(DataTable table in ds.Tables) {

  foreach(DataRow dr in table.Rows) {
   ctr = ctr + 1;

   routes.MapPageRoute("Route" + ctr, routeURL, routeHandler, false,
    new RouteValueDictionary {
     {
      "path",
      "page-not-found"
     }, {
      "pagename",
      "page-not-found"
     }
    });
  }
 }
```

Problem i am facing is that when ever i add new page to website using custom CMS i have to upload Gloabal.asax file again so that it compiles again and new routes take effect.

If i dont compile then new page added dont show.

How can run a code on button event so that i can force Global.asax file to recompile again.

I need this for asp.net webform website

Answer (score 1):

Here's [Editable Routes](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/17/editable-routes.aspx/) how to edit the routes dynamically without compiling. The example is for MVC but the author indicates that also works for WebForms.

There is also a library that can do that [RouteMagic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RouteMagic/).

Here [asp.net webforms dynamic routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109322/asp-net-webforms-dynamic-routing)  is a question from someone who does something similar in WebForms using that library.

Comment: I have to look into it as i have no MVC experience